# React-Native: How to include location details while capturing the image using expo-camera

Tags: expo, react-native, expo-camera

Developing a react-native app in that application accessing the Camera via `expo-camera` package, able to capture the image,

While accessing the the asset info of the captured image via `MediaLibrary.getAssetInfoAsync(asset)` the location field in the return object is null
[image]

is there any way to add the location details to the image or including the location information while capturing the image.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by inserting the GPS location directly into the image; in this example, I want my image in base64.

I used `piexifjs` and `expo-location`:

```
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
var piexif = require("piexifjs");

function degToDmsRational(degFloat) {
   degFloat = Math.abs(degFloat);
   var minFloat = degFloat % 1 * 60;
   var secFloat = minFloat % 1 * 60;
   var deg = Math.floor(degFloat);
   var min = Math.floor(minFloat);
   var sec = Math.round(secFloat * 100);

   deg = Math.abs(deg) * 1;
   min = Math.abs(min) * 1;
   sec = Math.abs(sec) * 1;

   return [[deg, 1], [min, 1], [sec, 100]];
}

const __pictureSave = async (newValue) => {
   let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();

   var data = Buffer.from(newValue.base64, 'base64').toString("binary");
   var exifObj = piexif.load(data);

   exifObj.GPS[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitude] = degToDmsRational(location.coords.latitude);
   exifObj.GPS[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLatitudeRef] = "N";
   exifObj.GPS[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitude] = degToDmsRational(location.coords.longitude);
   exifObj.GPS[piexif.GPSIFD.GPSLongitudeRef] = "W";

   var exifbytes = piexif.dump(exifObj);

   var newData = piexif.insert(exifbytes, data);
   var newJpeg = Buffer.from(newData, "binary");
   var newBase64 = newJpeg.toString('base64');

   onPictureSave("data:image/png;base64," + newBase64);
};
```